# Binding to events in dynamically loaded user controls

Tags: c#, dynamic, user-controls, event-handling

I am constructing a test project to demonstrate (to me) how to dynamically load user controls. Everything works except the wiring of the control to notify the parent that something has happened. The problem is with the line that tries to connect the event in the user control to the event handler in the parent page. The "NotifyParentEvent" event is not visible and the compiler barfs on it (the event is not defined in System.Web.UI.Control). I have tried using UserControl instead of Control, but to no avail.

```
Control control = Page.LoadControl(SavedControlVirtualPath);
if (control != null)
{
    control.ID = control.GetType().Name;
>>>>>    control.NotifyParentEvent += new EventHandler(UserControlNotificationHandler);
    controlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Code behind for User Control:

```
public partial class UserControls_WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event CommandEventHandler NotifyParentEvent;

    private void NotifyParent(string message)
    {
        if (NotifyParentEvent != null)
        {
            CommandEventArgs e = new CommandEventArgs("Control1 Action", message);
            NotifyParentEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Parent Page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string SavedControlVirtualPath
    {
        get {return (ViewState["savedControlPath"] == null || (string)ViewState["savedControlPath"] == string.Empty) 
                ? null : (string)ViewState["savedControlPath"]; }
        set { ViewState["savedControlPath"] = value; }
    }

    private void ReloadControl()
    {
        controlPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();
        if (SavedControlVirtualPath != null)
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(SavedControlVirtualPath);
            if (control != null)
            {
                // Gives the control a unique ID. It is important to ensure
                // the page working properly. Here we use control.GetType().Name
                // as the ID.
                control.ID = control.GetType().Name;
                control.NotifyParentEvent += new EventHandler(UserControlNotificationHandler); <== THIS LINE WON'T COMPILE
                controlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(control);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UserControlNotificationHandler(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //  ???
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblLastEvent.Text += "Page_Init<br />";
        LoadUserControls();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblLastEvent.Text += string.Format("{0} on main page<br />", (this.IsPostBack) ? "Postback" : "Page_Load");
        ReloadControl();
    }

    protected void rblControlSelector_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblLastEvent.Text += "rblControlSelector_Changed<br />";
        LoadUserControls();
    }

    private void LoadUserControls()
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        controlPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();
        switch (rblControlSelector.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "0":
                lblLastEvent.Text = "Unload/Clear<br />";
                SavedControlVirtualPath = "";
                break;

            case "1":
                lblLastEvent.Text += "Adding control #1<br />";
                SavedControlVirtualPath = "~/UserControls/WebUserControl1.ascx";
                break;

            case "2":
                lblLastEvent.Text += "Adding control #2<br />";
                SavedControlVirtualPath = "~/UserControls/WebUserControl2.ascx";
                break;

            case "3":
                lblLastEvent.Text += "Adding control #3<br />";
                SavedControlVirtualPath = "~/UserControls/WebUserControl3.ascx";
                break;

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SavedControlVirtualPath))
        {
            ReloadControl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: edited my question below, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

You need to cast you control to a type that implements the NotifyParentEvent event in order to attach the event handler. Basically, in your `ReloadControl` method, replace this line of code:

```
control.NotifyParentEvent += new EventHandler(UserControlNotificationHandler);
```

with the following:

```
if(control is UserControls_WebUserControl1) 
{
    (control as UserControls_WebUserControl1).NotifyParentEvent += new EventHandler(UserControlNotificationHandler);
}
```

**Option 2**

A more generic approach would be to create an interface and check if the dynamic control implements that interface.

Create the interface:

```
interface INotifyParent
{
    event CommandEventHandler NotifyParentEvent;
}
```

Implement the interface:

```
public partial class UserControls_WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, INotifyParent
{
    public event CommandEventHandler NotifyParentEvent;

    private void NotifyParent(string message)
    {
        if (NotifyParentEvent != null)
        {
            CommandEventArgs e = new CommandEventArgs("Control1 Action", message);
            NotifyParentEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Check if the dynamic control implements the interface:

```
if(control is INotifyParent) 
{
    (control as INotifyParent).NotifyParentEvent += new EventHandler(UserControlNotificationHandler);
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but this solution requires that I know each control's class name. I need a general solution that will dynamically determine in the NotifyParentHandler event is defined, and if so, hook it up.

Comment: You should then create an interface that exposes the event and have the controls implement the interface. This way you can cast to the interface type rather than to a concrete control type. It may also make sense to use a base class that implements the event so that you don't have to duplicate the code in each control.

Comment: Thanks to Vassili and Tim Stall's article (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110304-1.aspx), I got this working. It took a few tweaks, but if anybody wants the source code, just let me know.

Comment: control as INotifyParent was a good solution for me. @BobJones would you please comment your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the control to it's proper type before you add the eventhandler.

I'm not sure this will work, but try casting using the dynamic type rather than Control.

aka

```
dynamic control = Page.LoadControl(SavedControlVirtualPath);
```

This code assumes you are using .NET 4.0

Comment: Given that it is a dynamically loaded control, I am don't know it's proper type. Can you give me an example of the code you are thinking of? I suspect this may need "reflection" which I don't understand yet.